# Проблема инкапсуляции и вложенных классов

Tags: c#, .net, архитектура, проектирование, инкапсуляция

Есть вот такие типы (условно):

```
public class SomeClass
{
    readonly IEnumerable<SomeNestedStruct> structs;

    SomeClass(Builder builder)
    {
        // checks skipped

        structs = builder.structs;
    }

    public static Builder CreateBuilder() => new Builder();

    ⋮

    struct SomeNestedStruct // об этом типе знать должны только `SomeClass` и `SomeClass.Builder`
    {
        ⋮
    }
    public sealed class Builder
    {
        IEnumerable<SomeNestedStruct> structs; // проблемная строка

        internal Builder() { ... }

        public SomeClass Build() => new SomeClass(this);

        ⋮
    }
}
```

Дело в том, что классу `SomeClass` нужно получить доступ к приватному полю `structs` класса `SomeClass.Builder`. Его можно сделать `internal`, но в таком случае `internal` придётся делать и `SomeNestedStruct`, а это уже нарушение инкапсуляции: «об этом типе знать должны только `SomeClass` и `SomeClass.Builder`».

Каким образом лучше всего разрешить данную ситуацию? Или сама такая ситуация и загон архитектуры в неё является ошибкой? Или мой упрёк в нарушении инкапсуляции не имеет значимого веса как такового?

Comment: смотря что считать инкапсуляцией

Comment: @Grundy Можно по-конкретнее? Там же написано: "об этом типе знать должны только `SomeClass` и `SomeClass.Builder`".

Comment: есть разные варианты термина "инкапсуляция" - не во всех из них требуется сокрытие данных ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Grundy Я тоже видел видео бомбящего чела, который за сравнивание термина "сокрытие дынных" и "инкапсуляция" улетал на луну, но я же определил проблему.

Comment: Ы.З. Вот само [видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BHNt1fcg8iw) (4:52-7:51) (16+).

Comment: А как тут планируется builder использовать? Почему ему просто не возвращать созданный объект SomeClass?

Comment: @Grundy я скипнул прочие методы, т. к. они не важны. Если они вам так важны, я их покажу.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111559/discussion-between-grundy-and-return).

Comment: Вынести эти типы в отдельную сборку и сделать их `internal`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov не слишком жёстко?

Comment: Зато решает проблему на корню.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Давайте убьём всех оппозиционеров: это решает проблему на корню.

Comment: Вынесение некоторых типов в отдельную сборку - это нормальная практика разработки. Не понимаю, чем вам не нравится.

Comment: Ещё можно использовать атрибут `EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)`. Но это не работает в одном решении (solution). Применимо только если библиотека предназначена для использования в других проектах.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov вынести 1-3 класса в отдельную сборку: не слишком ли раздробительно? При этом эти классы связанны с др. классами в этой сборке.

Comment: Не знаю. Сложно сказать.

Comment: А если в конструктор сразу аргументом `structs` передать?

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov в чате нашёлся ответ, близкий к вашему